# Is it okay to escape data only when getting from database?

Tags: php, database, escaping

Is it okay to escape data only when getting from database ?
Or do i need also to escape input when sending it to database ?

A quick PHP question.

Thank you.

Comment: You only escape when sending data to, meaning data in any type of query SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)